take the same approach for + [two people]
I have a question in my mind about what preposition to use after "take the same approach" when it is followed by two people.
Let's say I want to express the idea that I treat Tom and John the same way. If I want to use "take the same approach", is "for" the correct preposition to use with it?
i.e. I take the same approach for both Tom and John.
If it's wrong, what preposition would native speakers normally use?

I would find with more idiomatic.

Thank you very much, Kate.

It's important to note that the choice of preposition isn't dependent on the same approach. It's all about the preceding verb...

As you can see, when you take an approach, it's usually with specific subjects, whereas if you use a method / approach, it's usually for. But it's no biggie either way, since obviously the "less-favoured" combinations do actually occur.

Thanks a lot. Does "to" also work in my sentence? As in "took the same approach to both Tom and John"?

Not really. There's no clear dividing line between "acceptable" and "unacceptable / invalid" preposition use, but took + to is definitely the wrong side of "acceptable". On the other hand, it's perfectly natural to apply the same technique to several different people / problems / tasks.
